# Get attribute values with xsi in XML node with Xpath query in SoapUI using Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Please find below the XML I am using, and I need to extract status of `mobileNumberVerified` in for my assertion validation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <AccountVerifyResponse xmlns="myservice url">
         <mobileNumberVerified xsi:nil="true" region="+91" />
      </AccountVerifyResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried xpath query `"//soapenv:Envelope[1]/soapenv:Body[1]/*:AccountVerifyResponse/*:mobileNumberVerified [1]/@*"` - I received "+91" which is as expected

and for xpath query `"//soapenv:Envelope[1]/soapenv:Body[1]/*:AccountVerifyResponse/*:mobileNumberVerified [1]/@xsi:nil"` - I got "path parser exception" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probaly making a mistake by not setting the namespace, examples of XPath and XQuery to get the attribute value and the tag value are given below

To get the attribute value

**Groovy :**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Add").getPropertyValue("response")
def holder = new XmlHolder(response)
holder.declareNamespace('ns1',"myservice url")
def attr1 = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:mobileNumberVerified/@*:nil")
def attr2 = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:mobileNumberVerified/@region")
log.info "Value of attribute is " + attr1
log.info "Value of attribute is " + attr2
```

**Script Assertion :**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
holder.namespaces["ns1"]="myservice url"

def attr1 = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:mobileNumberVerified/@*:nil")
def attr2 = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:mobileNumberVerified/@region")
```

To get the node value

**Groovy :**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Sample").getPropertyValue("response")
def holder = new XmlHolder(response)
holder.declareNamespace('ns1',"myservice url")

def value = holder.getNodeValue('//ns1:mobileNumberVerified/text()')

log.info value
```

**Script Assertion :**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
holder.namespaces["ns1"]="myservice url"

def node = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:mobileNumberVerified/text()")

//assert node==null
//assert node!=null
```

You could store the value into a property using groovy or you could also use **PropertyTranser**

```
declare namespace ns1='myservice url';
//ns1:AccountVerifyResponse/ns1:mobileNumberVerified/text()
```

[image]

**XQuery Match :**

```
declare namespace ns1='myservice url';
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope';

for $x in //ns1:AccountVerifyResponse
return
<status>{$x/ns1:mobileNumberVerified/text()}</status>
```

Comment: It worked, you were right.....I did miss the namespace. Thanks a lot for all the detailed information.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation, it says my upVote has been recorded  but not displayed. But i have accepted the answer :)